# Need json Data Pass Into Another Page For Listview

Tags: flutter, dart

i need to pass my data  into another page for listview.

how can i do this?

```
   Search() async {
   final Map<String, dynamic> jsondata = {
  "group_type": "${grptype.text}",
  "version_name": "${vername.text}",
   var jsonResponse = null;
   var response = await http.post("example.com/student-list/filtering",
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json",
    },
    body: jsondata);
    <code>   if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
   setState(() {
   print(jsonResponse['student_list'][0]['admission_year']);
```

**Here is my second Page**

```
          Route route=MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>stsearch());
             Navigator.push(context, route);
               print(jsonResponse); });
         } else {
            print(response.body);
           print(response.request);
            } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use route, and you can pass with arguments parameter 
create your argument class like this, you can put your json string or list in class

```
class ScreenArguments {
  final String title;
  final String message;

  ScreenArguments(this.title, this.message);
}
```

code snippet

```
RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Navigate to a named that accepts arguments"),
              onPressed: () {
                // When the user taps the button, navigate to a named route
                // and provide the arguments as an optional parameter.
                Navigator.pushNamed(
                  context,
                  PassArgumentsScreen.routeName,
                  arguments: ScreenArguments(
                    'Accept Arguments Screen',
                    'This message is extracted in the onGenerateRoute function.',
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
```

and get parameter class data with

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// Extract the arguments from the current ModalRoute settings and cast
// them as ScreenArguments.
   final ScreenArguments args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
```

full code 
the demo has two ways to extract argument 
Navigate to screen that extracts arguments and Navigate to a named that accepts arguments, 
you can pick one fit your situation

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // Provide a function to handle named routes. Use this function to
      // identify the named route being pushed, and create the correct
      // Screen.
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
        // If you push the PassArguments route
        if (settings.name == PassArgumentsScreen.routeName) {
          // Cast the arguments to the correct type: ScreenArguments.
          final ScreenArguments args = settings.arguments;

          // Then, extract the required data from the arguments and
          // pass the data to the correct screen.
          return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) {
              return PassArgumentsScreen(
                title: args.title,
                message: args.message,
              );
            },
          );
        }
      },
      title: 'Navigation with Arguments',
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home Screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            // A button that navigates to a named route that. The named route
            // extracts the arguments by itself.
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Navigate to screen that extracts arguments"),
              onPressed: () {
                // When the user taps the button, navigate to the specific route
                // and provide the arguments as part of the RouteSettings.
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => ExtractArgumentsScreen(),
                    // Pass the arguments as part of the RouteSettings. The
                    // ExtractArgumentScreen reads the arguments from these
                    // settings.
                    settings: RouteSettings(
                      arguments: ScreenArguments(
                        'Extract Arguments Screen',
                        'This message is extracted in the build method.',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            // A button that navigates to a named route. For this route, extract
            // the arguments in the onGenerateRoute function and pass them
            // to the screen.
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Navigate to a named that accepts arguments"),
              onPressed: () {
                // When the user taps the button, navigate to a named route
                // and provide the arguments as an optional parameter.
                Navigator.pushNamed(
                  context,
                  PassArgumentsScreen.routeName,
                  arguments: ScreenArguments(
                    'Accept Arguments Screen',
                    'This message is extracted in the onGenerateRoute function.',
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// A Widget that extracts the necessary arguments from the ModalRoute.
class ExtractArgumentsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/extractArguments';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Extract the arguments from the current ModalRoute settings and cast
    // them as ScreenArguments.
    final ScreenArguments args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(args.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(args.message),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// A Widget that accepts the necessary arguments via the constructor.
class PassArgumentsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/passArguments';

  final String title;
  final String message;

  // This Widget accepts the arguments as constructor parameters. It does not
  // extract the arguments from the ModalRoute.
  //
  // The arguments are extracted by the onGenerateRoute function provided to the
  // MaterialApp widget.
  const PassArgumentsScreen({
    Key key,
    @required this.title,
    @required this.message,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(message),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// You can pass any object to the arguments parameter. In this example,
// create a class that contains both a customizable title and message.
class ScreenArguments {
  final String title;
  final String message;

  ScreenArguments(this.title, this.message);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the first page do the following:

```
 Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => DetailScreen(response: jsonResponse),
                ),
              );
```

Then in the second page:

```
class DetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  // Declare a field that holds the Todo.
  final String response;

  // In the constructor, require a Todo.
  DetailScreen({Key key, @required this.response}) : super(key: key);
....
```

You will have the json repsonse inside the variable `response` in the second page.

Check here for more information:

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data#4-navigate-and-pass-data-to-the-detail-screen